# Minimize $\| A \cdot x\|$ with coupled $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n, B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. First we concat $y$ with 1 minus itself to get  $x:=[y, 1-y] \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Here $1$ is the constant one vector.
And we create a block diagonal matrix to get
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
        B\\&B
 \end{pmatrix} 
$$.

Now my question is given $B$, how can I find $y$ efficiently such that $\|Ax\|$ is minimized? Here $\|\cdot\|$ is the l2 norm.

Comment: Just minimise $\|By\|^2 + \|B(e-y)\|^2$. Or wrote $A$ a little differently and express it as a least squares problem directly.

Comment: Can you elaborate? There is no residual here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A x = \begin{bmatrix} B y \\ B (\mathbf{1} - y) \end{bmatrix} $

$ \| A x \|^2 = y^T B^T B y + (\mathbf{1} - y )^T B^T B (\mathbf{1} - y ) \\
= 2 y^T B^T B y - 2 y^T B^T B \mathbf{1} + \mathbf{1}^T B^T B \mathbf{1} $

So the minimum of this quadratic function occurs at

$ y = \dfrac{1}{2} (B^T B)^{-1} (B^T B) \mathbf{1} = \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{1} $

Comment: how did you get the minimum of this quadratic function that occurs right away?

Comment: If $Q$ is positive definite, then $f(x) = x^T Q x + b^T x + c $ has a minimum at $x_0= -\frac{1}{2} Q^{-1} b $.  This can be shown by completing the square, i.e. by showing that $f(x) = (x - x_0)^T Q (x - x_0) + c - x_0^T Q x_0 $

Answer (score 1):

Solve the least squares problem $\min_y \|\begin{bmatrix} B \\  -B \end{bmatrix}y - \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -B e \end{bmatrix}\|^2$.

$e=(1,...,1)^T$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wonder if adding a constraint $y \in \{0, 1\}^n$ would make the problem harder?

Comment: Probably, depends on $B$ but basically you are moving from solving the first order conditions to a combinatorial problem.